# UIImage show/hide in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am working on an iOS project that would like to showa and hide UIImages in an array for milliseconds in objective-c language. I don't know how?

Comment: Can you provide more information on the project, how is your code structured, what other actions are taking place, etc.?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Tell us what you trying to do, and with codes that you have tried.

Comment: can I send you my project so it would be best that you run it on your macbook?

Comment: here's my file in swift code:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PWCcn28zxhJqR-wIMWuonDk3I45goC6CuLfg3Z0OjXg/edit?usp=sharing

I'm trying to convert this into objective-c language. So far, I'm successful in working with the other items except for saving the highest score and show/hide images in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you’re looking for the animationImages property in the UIImageView class.  You can set an array of UIImages, a duration and a repeat count.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview/1621068-animationimages

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ryan, but I'm working in an objective-c language not swift.

Comment: here's my file in swift code:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PWCcn28zxhJqR-wIMWuonDk3I45goC6CuLfg3Z0OjXg/edit?usp=sharing

I'm trying to convert this into objective-c language. So far, I'm successful in working with the other items except for saving the highest score and show/hide images in milliseconds.